# Print number of times while loop executes

Tags: r, while-loop, coin-flipping

In the following code, the `while` loop will print the value of `z` until `z`  reaches 0 or 11, as its value is added or subtracted to by flips of a fair coin.

How would one also make this function print the number of times the coin is flipped?

```
z <- 5

while(z >= 1 && z <= 10) {
  print(z)
  coin <- rbinom(1, 1, 0.5)

  if(coin == 1) {
        z <- z +1 
  } else {
    z <- z -1
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the number of times the coin flipped as another variable, called `flips` in the code below. Then every time the while-loop executes, just increment `flips`. Then return `flips` at the end of the function.

```
coin_flip <- function(z) {

  flips <- 0

  while(z >= 1 && z <= 10) {
    print(z)
    coin <- rbinom(1, 1, 0.5)

    if(coin == 1) {
      z <- z +1 
    } else {
      z <- z -1
    }

    flips <- flips + 1

  }

  paste("The coin flipped", flips, "times.")

}

set.seed(1234)
coin_flip(5)
# [1] 5
# [1] 4
# [1] 5
# [1] 6
# [1] 7
# [1] 8
# [1] 9
# [1] 8
# [1] 7
# [1] 8
# [1] 9
# [1] 10
# [1] "The coin flipped 12 times."
```